# Is there a way to set when the bootstrap dropdown should turn into a dropup?

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown

The bootstrap 4 dropdown remains a dropdown until there is not enough space at the bottom of the browser window, then it changes to a dropup. Is there some way to make this happen when it's, say, 150px from the bottom rather than when it's at the bottom of the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be tricky to modify or add `JavaScript` for this. And it's unnecessary, because a simple hack to accomplish this is to add `margin-bottom` to the `.dropdown-menu.show` (don't forget to include `.show` in order to override the CSS).

For example, `margin-bottom: 150px`, preferably not inline. Then the menu will anticipate `150px` to change from `dropdown` to `dropup`.

You will then have to remove the `margin` when the `dropup` is active:

```
.dropdown-menu.show[x-placement="top-start"] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. The dropdown still only turns into dropup once it reaches the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Modified the answer. Added `.show` to the `.dropdown-menu`. You can test it.

Comment: I just tried it on codepen and it's working. There must but some other thing that's making it not work on my page. I'll figure it out. Thanks a lot!